# git mergers full path to files

Tags: git, parsing

Good day
I need to find a way to find the full path of changed files when reported after a git merge.
Git generally puts a .../rest/of/path/to/the/file if the path is too long.
But I am trying to parse it, and depending on the location of the file I want to be able to decide a suitable action while building (writing building scripts)
Is there a flag that I am missing, I read the manual pages and can't seem to find anything.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you've just done the merge, so I can refer to it as `HEAD`.

The automatic output of git merge is essentially `git diff-tree --stat -c HEAD`. (Or maybe `git diff --stat HEAD^ HEAD`; they're pretty much the same, and it's a call inside the git source, so six of one, half dozen of the other.) The `--stat` option gives you that "pretty" output. If you want to get the full information, the quickest way is:

```
git diff-tree -c --numstat HEAD
# or git diff --numstat HEAD^ HEAD
```

The first column is the number of added lines, the second is the number of deleted lines, and the third is the full filename.

If the merge is a ways back in the history, just replace HEAD with the appropriate SHA1. If the merge is in progress, and you're examining the merge you're *about* to commit (after having resolved conflicts, say), use `git diff --numstat --cached`.

Comment: Thank you, I was just coming back here to comment that I found --numstat :).
its what I need, I can ignore the numbers at first.
Thanks alot for your help.